# How can I keep focus of a JComboBox, when interaction with the JComboBox inside of a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtable, jcombobox

When using a JComboBox keyboard handling behavior changes when the combobox is embedded into a JTable.

E.g. JComboBox with the values [Item 1, Item 2, Item 3]:

**Standalone behavior:** you can step though all values by pressing the "i" several times.

**Embedded behavoir:** the comboxbox looses focus directly after pressing "i" once and the JComboBox value list collapses

From what I can gather the JTable adds additional key processing and gains somehow the focus although the JComboBox should keep it.

How can I prevent the JTable from gaining focus?

Comment: I think that there no answer(s) available without code in http://sscce.org/ form

Comment: I will try to come up with a lean example.

Answer (score 1):

```
Embedded behavoir: the comboxbox looses focus directly after pressing "i" once 
and the combobox value list collapses
```

I think that you have to look at [JTable's tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox), because [example from tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableRenderDemoProject/src/components/TableRenderDemo.java) is resist against keyboard issuses (as you described)